# change header image on post name

Tags: php, wordpress

I have many pages with a cover photo each that must be inserted into the header, but I cant seem to load the default header if it does not exist, or is the main blog page.

here is my code:

```
global $post;     // if outside the loop     
if ( is_home() ) {
    echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/our_clients.jpg' ; 
} else {
    get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cover_image', true);
}
```

What I need: if it is blog page, display: `echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/our_clients.jpg' ;` else display: `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cover_image', true);`

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
echo bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/our_clients.jpg' ;
```

will get the URL of your default image, but to display it, you will need to put that URL in an img src attribute.  So, you can change the above line to:

```
echo '<img src="' . bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/our_clients.jpg" />';
```

Also, change

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cover_image', true);
```

to

```
echo '<img src="' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cover_image', true); . '" />';
```